# How to catch a specific exception if the possible list of exceptions are too many?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, sonarqube

I have this piece of code where I am trying to save some information to a file

```
try
{
    foreach (var str in strlist)
    {
        var jsonData = str;
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)+"test\"+".json",jsonData.ToString());
        savedFiles++;
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    _log.ErrorFormat("Exception occurred in Saving JsonDocs , exception Message {0}", exception.Message);
    return savedFiles;

}
```

When I checked in this code, My SONAR started complaining that I should catch **specific exceptions**.

But the only logic which I have here is a **File** Saving which can have all the below possible exceptions

[image]

So if a File operation can throw exceptions of 8 types, How can I catch a specific exception? Does it mean I have to write multiple catch blocks?

Comment: First work out what [category](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) each possible exception is in. For instance, an `ArgumentException` - you shouldn't have to catch one because you shouldn't be passing faulty arguments to the function in the first place.

Comment: All derive from SystemException. What if you catch that? If it is OK, you should include in your log file the type of the exception too, with exception.GetType(). I also observe that you only keep a count of saved files, and not the state for each file. You should really consider keeping track of the status of save operations for each file, not just the count of successful saves.

Answer (score 3):

> So if a File operation can throw exceptions of 8 types, How can I
>   catch a specific exception? Does it mean I have to write multiple
>   catch blocks?

Yes, you'll need to write specific `catch` clauses for each exception you want to catch, going from the specific ones to the general ones.

[The documentation on `try-catch` is pretty clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.80).aspx):

> It is possible to use more than one specific catch clause in the same
>   try-catch statement. In this case, the order of the catch clauses is
>   important because the catch clauses are examined in order. Catch the
>   more specific exceptions before the less specific ones. The compiler
>   produces an error if you order your catch blocks so that a later block
>   can never be reached.

```
try
{
    foreach (var str in strlist)
    {
        var jsonData = str;
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)+
                          "test\"+".json", jsonData.ToString());
        savedFiles++;
    }
}
catch (PathTooLongException pe)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    _log.ErrorFormat("Exception occurred in Saving JsonDocs , 
                      exception Message {0}", exception.Message);
    return savedFiles;
}
```

Means that if an `PathTooLongException` is thrown, it will be caught by that catch clause. If you mistakenly switched the order of the catch clause and had `Exception` first, it would take priority over any other exception handling clause.

Comment: Thanks, So if there is any method which can 'N' exceptions should i write 'N' catch blocks. That will make the method too big and 'N' unit test cases should also be written?

Comment: @CSharped There is no general guideline, but usually yes. It is uncommon for methods to throw so many exceptions. For example, `ArgumentException` and `ArgumentNullException` aren't exceptions you really want to "handle", you simply want to fix the calling code. More-so, most of the time you'll want to do something more general with your exceptions, such as log.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. You need to catch and handle every exception type.

However, `ArgumentNullException` is inherited from `ArgumentException`. Also, `PathTooLongException` and `DirectoryNotFoundException` are both `IOException`s.

So, actually, you will need to handle 5 exception types, but not 8.

Comment: Thanks, So what happens if I have a  catch block for specific exception, and there is no catch block for a general exception. But the exception which occured is of a different type

Answer (score 0):

In the given example I would add catch blocks for the IO exceptions, because these are the ones that can really occur at runtime due to real IO problems. All other exceptions can only be thrown for dramatic problems you can never handle anyway or for errors in your surrounding code. for example, there could be a `null` string in your list that leads to an `ArgumentException`.

In the latter case, there is something wrong with your application and it should rather crash than proceed it's work in an unspecifed state.